# Collapse Header View without Toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to collapse my header view in my fragment. I've tried using Collapsing Toolbar layout but it's not working. My toolbar is in my activity and my header and everything else is in a fragment. Any tips on how to achieve this? I'll post the codes of each page

**fragment_post.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainImageContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/purple"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/numPosts"
                    android:layout_width="36dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_comments_bubble"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/purple"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="2.4"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/threadTopic"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:alpha="0.5"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/threadText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/moreOptions"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_more_vert_white_24dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/postsRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </LinearLayout>



    <View
        android:id="@+id/scrimColorView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black_semi_transparent"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/flipText"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:text="@string/flipText"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/flipFab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_flip"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/mnBlue"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                app:elevation="6dp"
                app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/shareText"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:text="@string/shareText"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/shareFab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/mnBlue"
                app:elevation="6dp"
                app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/replyText"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-46dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:text="@string/replyText"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>


            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/replyFab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_reply"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/mnBlue"
                app:elevation="6dp"
                app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/mnBlue"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**activity_post_pager.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarForPosts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentInsetStart="67dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/search_button"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_search"
                android:src="@android:color/transparent"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/postPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you only changing text in header then , You can set activity title using method of activity setTitle("text") from your fragment using method.

Comment: @GiteekaSawlani sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say?